DB2 AS400 Table partitioning - execution plan for specific partition
Due to constantly increasing number of data stored in our system running on DB2 AS400 7.3 database we decided to introduce table partitioning on some tables. While creation of partitioned tables works fine, we have some problems with analizing execution plans for our queries. Lets assume the simplest table with around 50mln records, partitioned by column YEAR (range 2020 - 2024). Each partition contains lets say 10mln records. In table QSYS2.SYSPARTITIONSTAT we can see confirmation that partitions are created properly (the amount of data in each partition is good as well). We want to test the mechanism of partitioned table by running the simplest possible query:
select * from dbschema.PARTITIONED_TABLE where YEAR = 2023.

So we want to ask for the data from only one specific partition (by partitioning key YEAR).
We thought that DB2 will optimize the query execution plan and only one partition will be accessed by that query. Instead in execution plan generated by System and Navigator (Run and Explain) we can see, that SQE makes table scan and all members of the tables where analized (Member of table being queried - *ALL).

Do we miss something or DB2 AS400 simply do not have that kind of mechanism, that allows to skip searching in partitions which partition keys do not fulfill conditions specified in where clause?
Is there any chance to check which partitions where exactly taken for query execution? Maybe there is a system table or a command that allows to observe that.
One of our goal is also to optimize the queries, so we thought that table partitioning can help us but we are not so sure now. What worked for us, was to make alias for specific partition and then use alias in the query. But that is not a solution for our system.
Thanks for your help.

A partitioned-index also exists with the partitioning-key as first column?

So far no. As a first step we just wanted to test the mechanism without indexes. Later on we planned to create proper partitioned-indexes. Shouldn't it worked also without indexes?

From what I recall, SQE gets statistics slightly differently - I would check Statistics Manager to make sure all the changes you did to this table are reflected by the statistics, which are then used by SQE to write the plan.

show the DDL used to create the table.

ALTER TABLE TABLE_SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
ADD PARTITION BY RANGE(YEAR)
(STARTING(2020) ENDING(2020) INCLUSIVE,
STARTING(2021) ENDING(2021) INCLUSIVE,
STARTING(2022) ENDING(2022) INCLUSIVE,
STARTING(2023) ENDING(2023) INCLUSIVE,
STARTING(2024) ENDING(2024) INCLUSIVE);

The Check constraint optimization page of the docs certainly reads to me as if you should expect the Db2 to only look at the 2023 partition.

In the following example, assume that PAYROLL is partitioned by range (on EMPNUM):
SELECT LASTNAME, SALARY
  FROM PRODLIB.PAYROLL 
  WHERE EMPNUM = :hv1

The optimizer adds new predicates to each partition in the table:
SELECT LASTNAME, SALARY FROM 
  (SELECT LASTNAME, SALARY FROM  PRODLB.PAYROLL(PART00001)
   WHERE EMPNUM=:hv1 AND :hv1 <= 500
   UNION ALL
      SELECT LASTNAME, SALARY FROM  PRODLB.PAYROLL(PART00002)
   WHERE EMPNUM=:hv1 AND :hv1 >= 501 AND :hv1 <=1000 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT LASTNAME, SALARY FROM  PRODLB.PAYROLL(PART00003)
   WHERE EMPNUM=:hv1 AND (:hv1 IS NULL OR :hv1 >= 1001))
  X (LASTNAME, SALARY)  

If the value of hv1 is 603, then only the rows of partition PART00002
are examined.

I'd check to make sure you are current on PTFs for the OS, particularly the DB group PTF.
Also that you're running the latest version of ACS.  Could just be a bug in how the data is being shown by Explain.
You might need to get IBM involved.
